# ¿Mostrar botones debajo de un TR?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, tablas

¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar botones debajo de un `<tr>` con JavaScript?
Esta es la tabla que tengo de ejemplo:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class = "trMember">
<td class="table-default">Nombre</td>
<td class="table-default">Apellido</td>
<td class="table-default">Conexión</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

La tabla realmente se llena mediante JavaScript y tengo la función al hacer clic al `trMember`

```
$(document).on('click', '.trMember', function (argument) {
    //Código
})
```

La ídea es mostrar botones debajo del `tr` sin eliminar los que están abajo, pero con `$('#tabla').html();` tendría que añadir los botones y volver a llenar los `tr` debajo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No me quedó del todo claro pero creo que  lo que quieres es algo así. Primero he añadido bajo cada fila, otra fila oculta con botones. A demás, también creo la etiqueta `data-index` para marcar el índice de la fila. Esta etiqueta relacionará la fila con su botonera.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class = "trMember" data-index="0">
      <td class="table-default">Nombre1</td>
      <td class="table-default">Apellido1</td>
      <td class="table-default">Conexión1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trButtons" data-index="0">
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón1</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón2</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón3</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "trMember" data-index="1">
      <td class="table-default">Nombre2</td>
      <td class="table-default">Apellido2</td>
      <td class="table-default">Conexión2</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="trButtons" data-index="1">
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón1</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón2</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón3</button></td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.trButtons { display:none; }
.trMember.selected { background-color:gray; }
```

Luego he creado una clase CSS para mostrar las botoneras:

```
.trButtons.selected { display:block; }
```

Y por último, utilizo javascript para mostrar/ocultar las botoneras:

```
$(document).on('click', '.trMember', function (argument) {
    // Marca la fila seleccionada
    $('#tbl1').find('tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    // Busca la botonera a partir del índice y la marca como seleccionada
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    $('#tbl1').find("tr.trButtons[data-index='" + index + "']").addClass('selected');
})
```

Todo junto quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.trMember', function (argument) {
  // Marca la fila seleccionada
  $('#tbl1').find('tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    // Busca la botonera a partir del índice y la marca como seleccionada
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    $('#tbl1').find("tr.trButtons[data-index='" + index + "']").addClass('selected');
})
```

```css
.trButtons { display:none; }
.trButtons.selected { display:block; }
.trMember.selected { background-color:gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class = "trMember" data-index="0">
      <td class="table-default">Nombre1</td>
      <td class="table-default">Apellido1</td>
      <td class="table-default">Conexión1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trButtons" data-index="0">
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón1</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón2</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón3</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "trMember" data-index="1">
      <td class="table-default">Nombre2</td>
      <td class="table-default">Apellido2</td>
      <td class="table-default">Conexión2</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr class="trButtons" data-index="1">
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón1</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón2</button></td>
      <td class="table-default"><button>Botón3</button></td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda zeross, me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

para agregar los botones yo agregaria debajo de la etiqueta **tbody** un **tfooter** y allí los agregaría!.

Ejemplo:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class = "trMember">
<td class="table-default">Nombre</td>
<td class="table-default">Apellido</td>
<td class="table-default">Conexión</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfooter>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
</tfooter>
</table>
```

PD: No olvides definir tu tfooter en tu pagina de CSS, Suerte!.

Comment: La idea es que los botones se muestren debajo del <tr>, no debajo de todos los <tr>, no se si me explico...

Comment: Por favor si puedieras explicarte de otra manera, ya que la parte de "debajo del <tr>, no debajo de todos los <tr>" me sugiere que quieres que debajo de nombre un boton, debajo de apellido otro boton, algo asi ?

Comment: La "<tr>" es la fila, mostrar eso, sólo debajo de la fila seleccionada.

Comment: Estimado, te añado la documentacion en bootstrap 4 respecto a las <tr>

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/

Answer (score 0):

podrías targetear al parent de tu `<tr>` o sea al `<tbody>` y ahí se insertará abajo de todos los hijos de `<tbody>`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.trMember', function (argument) {
    $(this).parent()
})
```

Comment: Pero la idea es mostrarlo debajo del `<tr>` seleccionado.